# Get points enclosed by a 3d polygon

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, 3d

I have a polygon that lies on a 3D plane. i want to get all points enclosed by this polygon.can anyone help me ?
 i can make a 3D scan line algorithm by replacing the scan lines by planes and get the intersection of planes with my polygon but i want a faster solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any additonal assumptions available? For example, is your mesh convex (that would make the problem *much* easier)

Comment: Ow, ow! Maybe I (and many other people who responded) misunderstood you. Do you have a 2D polygon somewhere in 3D space? But if that is the case, then the problem can be solved in 2D-local-coordinate space of that plane.

Comment: yes it's a  convex 3p polygon ,but it all its points lie in the same plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"yes it's a convex 3p polygon ,but it all its points lie in the same plane"

In that case - just convert the polygon and all the test points into 2D local coordinates of the plane and use a 2D algorithm:

- 2D ray shooting: You can still use similar algorithm to my 3d suggestion - shoot 2D rays originating from your test point and count how many times you hit the border of your polygon.
- Linear inequalities: If your polygon is convex, you can follow suszterpatt's approach, with your polygon defined as an intersection of halfplanes `ax+by<d`

Further reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon
- http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
- http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/

Answer (score 5):

One approach that I can see right now is to shoot an <del>random</del> arbitrary ray from each point that you want to verify and count how many times it intersects with the surface of your 3d mesh. If it is odd - it is inside, if even - outside.

Comment: Thanks Cygnus for your help but this is the point in  poylgon test.. the problem is that i want to get all the points in this polygon so i cant limit the number of generated random point that i should test

Comment: There is no limit on the number of points that you can test. You just shoot the arbitrary ray for every point you test.

Answer (score 2):

If your polygon is convex, then you can use the following approach:

Each face of the polygon is part of a plane given by the equation `ax + by + cz = d`. Find this equation for all faces, modify them to `< d` or `> d` depending on which relation describes points on the inside of the polygon, then solve this system of linear inequalities. This should give you a set of relations for x, y, and z that only points inside the polygon satisfy.

Comment: This will work only with an assuption that the 3d mesh is convex!

Answer (score 1):

CygnusX1's answer is the standard point-in-a-polygon test, and can be modified for a variety of different systems (eg. I have a version coded for working on a spheroid). The main trick when adapting it is deciding on the ray direction. 'Abitrary' s a much better word than 'random'.  For 2d Euclidean work I would shoot it in a direction parallel to one of the axes (and perpendicular to the other). For a sphere, you use one of the poles.  For a 2d planar polygon in 3d, then I would be tempted to choose a line that is perpendicular to one of the axes.

Or I would transform my coordinates so that all calculations are in the plane. This will greatly simplify the actual point-in-polygon test. I think this will also be faster (significantly so for large polygons and many tests): each polygon corner only needs to be transformed once, but it will be used in two tests per point-in-polygon test.

Comment: Agreed, "arbitrary" is a better word. Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Project your polygon onto the (x,y)-plane. Now it's a 2-D problem. Each point (x,y) inside the 2-D projection represents a point (x,y,z) inside the 3-D polygon.
Note: If your plane is perpendicular to the (x,y)-plane, this won't work; and if it is nearly perpendicluar, you will get a loss of precision. So in practice, you would project onto the coordinate plane that is least perpendicular to your 3-D plane.

Comment: Normally you project your plane on X,Y,Z according to the longest component of the normal to your plane, i.e if your normal vector n =(1,2,3) then you should project it on XY plane

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something similar implemented using one of matplotlib/scipy/numpy. I can't exactly remember the algorithm however, see whether [this](http://ask.scipy.org/en/topic/5-efficient-inside-polygon-test-for-an-array) helps.